# Does PostgreSQL allow multiple grantees in GRANT commands?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, users

Looking at the PostgreSQL docs it seems that the GRANT command only grants to a single user or role. In fact it doesn't seem to be PostgreSQL alone.

Isn't possible to do something like `GRANT SELECT UPDATE ON atable TO mary, bob, sue`?

It looks like a major omission to me, or is there some reason, historical or practical for it?

Comment: I guess because a role can be associated with many users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes [it does](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html), but that will turn into a maintenance headache down the road.

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control for justification for assigning rights to roles over individual users.

Simply create a role and assign users to it, and then grant privileges to that role.

```
create role some_group;

grant some_group to mary, bob, sue;

grant select, update on a_table to some_group;
```

Comment: Does this sequence in the syntax`[, ...]`  as in `TO { [ GROUP ] rolename | PUBLIC }` mean comma separated instances of the symbols to the left of it?

Comment: @vfclists yes. This would be valid: `grant select on a_table to group1, group2, group3`